# Centering one component vertically and appbar at top of the screen material UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to material UI, and am having problems centering a component (horizontally and vertically) whilst including an AppBar for navigation at the top my screen. I understand that there are solutions like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pngrxbm5l), using a grid, however, this will align ALL items, including my AppBar in the middle, which I do not want. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been pulling out my hair trying to work this out (I'm usually a backend dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is to position your AppBar `sticky` as a sibling of an element containing the "main" section of your app.

A standard approach would be the following (I will use `Grid` since you are using `material-ui`):

```html
<Grid id="whole-app" style={{ position: "relative", height: "90vh" }}>
  <Grid
    id="appbar"
    style={{ position: "sticky", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}
  >
    Some AppBar content
  </Grid>
  <Grid
    id="main"
    container
    justify="center"
    alignItems="center"
    style={{ height: "inherit" }}
  >
    <div>Main section</div>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-fast-m2h9t?file=/src/App.js).

You can see the rationale: We have a container element that has a height and is positioned (`#whole-app`) and has two children, the sticky `AppBar` and the main content area. The main section container has `display: flex` (the `container` prop), a height so you can see the vertical alignment and the corresponding props for centering its children.

Your code sandbox was buggy because `align` is not a valid `Grid` prop and you don't need the `spacing` prop.

As a side note, I suggest you check [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/), which I think is easier for beginners.

Answer (score -2):

You can center any element adding display flex to the parent component as follows:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```